# Second "To Be" with Irrealis/Past Subjunctive

Tags: past-tense, subjunctive-mood, be, adverbials, irrealis-were

Assuming that I'm a person who uses irrealis subjunctive, and every part of the example situation is hypothetical, which of the following is more correct?

Option 1: *If I were ever in a store where I was/wasn't satisfied...*

Option 2: *If I were ever in a store where I were/weren't
 satisfied...*

The second option sounds awkward to me. Does the subjunctive mood not carry through to the second *to be*, even though it's part of an adverbial phrase linked to the counterfactual? What's going on there?

Comment: I do not believe it is idiomatic, in modern English, to continue the subjunctive into the adverbial phrase. At least it doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: If I were ever in a store and were I not satisfied...

Comment: The first is fine; the second simply horrible.

Why did you not ask that at English Language Learners, please?